# OpenXML Power Tools trouble compiling: 'OutputTypeAttribute' could not be found

Tags: c#, powershell, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am using the OpenXMLSDK for some DOCX manipulation.  I am trying to compile the [OpenXML Power Tools](http://powertools.codeplex.com/releases/view/74771) source for help with this.  I read that I needed to instal the MS Power Shell for this to compile (for its use of Cmdlets), so I downloaded it from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/12/30/download-windows-powershell.aspx).  The first option, Windows Management Framework 3.0 CTP1.  I am still having problems with the OutpuTypeAttribute class.  It is not available in my code.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.outputtypeattribute%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says its in the System.Management.Automation namespace, which I am 'using'. I am still getting this error message for any references to this class:

"The type or namespace name 'OutputTypeAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

So, does anyone know what is going on here?

BTW, I am on Windows 7 and using VS 2010.

Comment: Windows 7 already has PowerShell 2.0. You downloaded an old community technical preview of an upcoming, unreleased version of PowerShell. This might be adding to your problem...

Comment: @AndyArismendi I had the same problems before installing that version of PowerShell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason the C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\System.Management.Automation.dll was an old version and it never got updated.

What I did was this:
In a powershell I executed this command:

```
Copy ([OutputType].Assembly.Location) ~/Desktop
```

Then I moved the dll file that is copied to the desktop to the Reference Assemblies directory shown above.  This new file is about 3mb larger than the older file.  I also had to convert my project to .NET 4 because this new DLL required it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it can help but `System.Management.Automation` can be referenced from two places :

For 64 bits :

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

For 32 bits :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

I remember that I use to have a kind of similary error using one in place of the other.